# network switch features recommended for use with open vswitch

Tags: openvswitch, openflow

I am looking to setup openvswitch to use with a handful (<10) servers and need a couple of ethernet switches to implement this.

Are there any features that are recommended to be present in the physical switches that would enable the overlay network features?

Is VLAN support enough or would I need a switch that has some basic OpenFlow support ( like HP 2920 ), or other hardware feature support?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for asking a "What to look out for" question instead of "Tell me what to buy".